# How can I display the date and time in dayjs 12hours clock? using dayjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, dayjs

This is my first time using dayjs because of mui date time picker.
[image]

so in this image, I already get the transaction, but the problem  is the current Time. I only like to get the date, day, hour, and minutes.

```
 2022-11-14T14:42:30.080Z
```

so in here instead of showing

I would like to receive

```
 2022-11-14 10:42 PM
```

this is my table cell

```
<TableCell align="left">{recent.location} & {recent.time}</TableCell>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dayjs(YOUR_DATE).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A')
```